# Get data from AJAX request in NodeJS and store in DB

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, node.js, body-parser

I have a problem with getting data from client side in NodeJS.

On the client side I've prepared JSON data as you can see in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJyear?editors=101)

On the server side I'm trying to get these data from the client:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('../client/app'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static('../client/bower_components/'));

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
app.urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

//mysql connection setup
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    port: "3306",
    user : "root",
    password : "",
    database : "db",
    multipleStatements: true
});

app.get("/cities", function(req, res) {

    console.log(res.body); //I'm getting nothing

    var data= {
        city: req.body.city,
        country: req.body.country
    };

    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO table SET ?', data, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('success');    
        }
    });
    console.log(res); 
});
    
server.listen(3000, function () {
    'use strict';
});
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to debug NodeJS in ST?
Thanks.

Comment: `database : "",` no db selected.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it in example above, but that isn't a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this `req.params.city` to fetch input data. It works in my project. However, `req.body` I use for getting data sent through POST method.

> app.get - use req.params
>   app.post - use req.body

Comment: I've changed to req.params, but I still cannot get data from client :/ { city: undefined, country: undefined }

Comment: try : app.get("/cities/:city/:country", function(){ console.log(req.params.city); });           AND send in url like : http://localhost:3000/cities/london/britain

Comment: I would like to store all data from JSON (not specific field like ) to db and I'm a little bit confused about API form in NodeJS. Do you have any suggestion for that solution? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using :- var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.post("/cities", function(){ console.log(req.body); });   this will work when request sent in post (x-www-form-urlencode)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
console.log(res.body); //I'm getting nothing
```

I think you have to send the response as `res.send('success')`. Or you might try sending the posted values again to test:

```
res.send(data);
```

like:

```
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO table SET ?', data, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('success');  
        res.send(res.insertId);  
    }
});
```

Comment: When I'm trying to access api (cities), I got TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined error :/ It's a first property of data object.